# Python, I want to login to my Google account with Requests Library

Tags: python, post, python-requests, http-post, python-requests-html

I tried to login to my google account with the requests library, but I couldn't, can anyone help?

I couldn't find how to post the data it's too complicated, or i dumb... I can see the data in the form data, but I could not post it somehow.

Comment: Dear Kennys Arnold, welcome to Stackoverflow. You just need to copy-paste the code that is getting you the error, and the Traceback that you get from it. You can also include screenshots as long as they are not images of code. Please read [how to post a minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [why not to include images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

It's nearly impossible to login to google account with any standalone library.

So instead you can try using google api documentation for your specific need. Here's a [documentation for gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides) for example. This documentation provides a very good step by step guide on how to write your own script for gmail.